# Read-side latency and responsivness

Tags: mysql, scala, lagom

I am using Lagom with MySQL and I am having latency issue. I am using ES and CQRS. I have intergrated my backend service and frontend service and now facing some issue. I have to refresh my page each time to get the response since it took some time to store in the MySQL database. There is a lag in getting stored and thus fetching data from the database is giving late response.
Is there a way to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

I have tried providing some settings in the configuration file but doesn't get the desired result.

```
lagom.persistence.jdbc {

 # Configuration for creating tables
 create-tables {

   # Whether tables should be created automatically as needed
   auto = true

   # How long to wait for tables to be created, before failing
   timeout = 20s

   # The cluster role to create tables from
   run-on-role = ""

   # Exponential backoff for failures configuration for creating tables
   failure-exponential-backoff {

     # minimum (initial) duration until processor is started again
     # after failure
     min = 3s

     # the exponential back-off is capped to this duration
     max = 30s

     # additional random delay is based on this factor
     random-factor = 0.2
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot solve this issue in ES and CQRS, because one of the goals of it to separate writing and reading parts. So, that you read side projection and writing part can have different values some time it is normal.

You cant try to read from persistent entity directly;